# How to make arithmetic operations inside a txt file and show the result on another txt file?

Tags: java

i'm having some problems on an exercise i have for my Java class. What i need to do is put some info inside a "enter.txt" file, something like

```
Hello
5.0
+
5.0
World
```

and on a "out.txt" i need to print the result of the arithmetic operation, it should appear something like this:

```
Hello
10.0
World
```

I already did the part of printing the contents of the "enter.txt" to the "out.txt" but i tried to do the arithmetic operations part with no result, i have an error on the console.

```
C:\Users\PC\Desktop>java miCalc enter.txt out.txt
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at miCalc.<init>(miCalc.java:35)
        at miCalc.main(miCalc.java:11)
```

And here's the code of the Java programm:

```
import java.io.*;
public class miCalc{
String input, output;
char operacion;
String[] num;
float resultado;
String dataFiles;
public static void main(String args[]){
    String input = args[0];
    String output = args[1];
    miCalc fileOp = new miCalc(input,output);
}
public miCalc(String input, String output){
    this.input = input;
    this.output = output;
    try{
        File f1 = new File(input);
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(f1);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(output,true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        do{
            dataFiles=br.readLine();
            if(dataFiles!=null){
                for(int i=0;i<dataFiles.length();i++){
                    if(dataFiles.charAt(i)=='+' || dataFiles.charAt(i)=='-' || dataFiles.charAt(i)=='*' || dataFiles.charAt(i)=='/'){
                        operacion=dataFiles.charAt(i);
                    }
                }
                String c=operacion+"";
                num=dataFiles.split("\\"+c);
                if(operacion=='+'){
                    resultado=Float.parseFloat(num[0])+Float.parseFloat(num[1]);
                    bw.write(resultado+"");
                    bw.newLine();
                }

                else if(operacion=='-'){
                    resultado=Float.parseFloat(num[0])-Float.parseFloat(num[1]);
                    bw.write(resultado+"");
                    bw.newLine();
                }
                else if(operacion=='*'){
                    resultado=Float.parseFloat(num[0])*Float.parseFloat(num[1]);
                    bw.write(resultado+"");
                    bw.newLine();
                }
                else if(operacion=='/'){
                    resultado=Float.parseFloat(num[0])/Float.parseFloat(num[1]);
                    bw.write(resultado+"");
                    bw.newLine();
                }

            }
        }while(dataFiles!=null);
            br.close();
            bw.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){}
    catch(IOException e){}
}
}
```

Any idea of what is making that error or there's a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: step through your code with a debugger and find the error

Comment: At first glance, it looks like your `Split` operation may not be working right - what's the result of that operation?

Comment: Yeah i though the same about the split operation, but when i compile the code i have that error i specified on the post. I looked for any other ways to do the operations inside the file but i haven't found something that could work on my code unfortunately.  I think is something about the "num" variable too.

Comment: Each readline() call is only giving you access to the current line, not all lines.  Print out a line number and datafiles as each line is read to see what I mean.  Basically store the first number and operation and don't perform the operation until the second number is read.  Your're processing too early(operation is non-null before the second number is read)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, now i understand a bit now. Do you think is necessary to use split in this case?

Comment: Throw it all away and look up how to parse and evaluate expressions properly. You need an expression parser. This is a solved problem since about 1960. You don't need to invent a solution.